# AEM 6.5 publisher not starting

Tags: java, adobe, aem

I have followed the steps listed out [here](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-learn/cloud-service/local-development-environment-set-up/aem-runtime.html?lang=en#) for setting up my local AEM instances. The author is running just fine. the publisher instance is not, going to `http://localhost:4503` redirects me to `http://localhost:4503/content.html` and i get this error:

```
Not Found

Cannot serve request to /content.html in org.apache.sling.servlets.get.DefaultGetServlet
```

I read somewhere that this is expected because `/content.html` does not exist on the publisher instance and that i should instead go to `http://localhost:4503/aem/start.html` which gives me this error:

```
Resource at '/libs/granite/ui/content/shell/start.html' not found: No resource found

Cannot serve request to /aem/start.html in BundledScriptServlet (/libs/sling/servlet/errorhandler/404.jsp)
```

I am at a loss, any help would be great.

Additional info:

`license.properties`

I do not have my license.properties file as of yet and my understanding is that AEM should start the publish instance (just like the author instance) just fine with out it, but will be required after startup.

`java -version`

```
java version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.12+8-LTS-237)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.12+8-LTS-237, mixed mode)
```

`stdout.log`

```
Loading quickstart properties: instance
Quickstart startup at Fri May 13 09:19:01 EDT 2022
UpgradeUtil.handleInstallAndUpgrade has mode INSTALL
13.05.2022 09:19:03.609 *INFO * [main] Setting sling.home=/Users/<user>/aem-sdk/publish/crx-quickstart (command line)
13.05.2022 09:19:03.610 *INFO * [main] Starting Apache Sling in /Users/<user>/aem-sdk/publish/crx-quickstart
13.05.2022 09:19:03.612 *INFO * [main] Sling  Extension Lib Home : /Users/<user>/aem-sdk/publish/crx-quickstart/launchpad/ext
13.05.2022 09:19:03.612 *INFO * [main] Checking launcher JAR in folder /Users/<user>/aem-sdk/publish/crx-quickstart/launchpad
13.05.2022 09:19:03.621 *INFO * [main] Installing new launcher: jar:file:/Users/<user>/aem-sdk/publish/crx-quickstart/app/cq-quickstart-cloudready-2022.4.7138.20220427T075748Z-220401-standalone-quickstart.jar!/resources/org.apache.sling.launchpad.base.jar, 7.0.3.2_7_6 (org.apache.sling.launchpad.base.jar.1652447943621)
13.05.2022 09:19:03.622 *INFO * [main] Loading launcher class org.apache.sling.launchpad.base.app.MainDelegate from org.apache.sling.launchpad.base.jar.1652447943621
13.05.2022 09:19:03.622 *INFO * [main] External Libs Home (ext) is null or does not exists.
13.05.2022 09:19:03.628 *INFO * [main] Setting sling.properties=conf/sling.properties
13.05.2022 09:19:03.628 *INFO * [main] Setting sling.home=/Users/<user>/aem-sdk/publish/crx-quickstart
13.05.2022 09:19:03.628 *INFO * [main] Setting sling.launchpad=/Users/<user>/aem-sdk/publish/crx-quickstart/launchpad
13.05.2022 09:19:03.628 *INFO * [main] Setting org.osgi.service.http.port=4503
13.05.2022 09:19:03.628 *INFO * [main] Starting launcher ...
13.05.2022 09:19:03.633 *INFO * [main] HTTP server port: 4503
13.05.2022 09:19:06.911 *INFO * [main] Startup completed
13.05.2022 09:19:10.711 *INFO* [OsgiInstallerImpl] org.apache.sling.audit.osgi.installer Started bundle org.apache.sling.discovery.api [44]
13.05.2022 09:19:10.712 *INFO* [OsgiInstallerImpl] org.apache.sling.audit.osgi.installer Started bundle org.apache.sling.provisioning.model [45]
13.05.2022 09:19:10.712 *INFO* [OsgiInstallerImpl] org.apache.sling.audit.osgi.installer Started bundle com.adobe.granite.startup [46]
13.05.2022 09:19:10.713 *INFO* [OsgiInstallerImpl] org.apache.sling.audit.osgi.installer Started bundle com.adobe.cq.cq-deserialization-firewall [47]
13.05.2022 09:19:10.713 *INFO* [OsgiInstallerImpl] org.apache.sling.audit.osgi.installer Started bundle org.apache.felix.eventadmin [48]
13.05.2022 09:19:10.713 *INFO* [OsgiInstallerImpl] org.apache.sling.audit.osgi.installer Started bundle org.apache.felix.healthcheck.api [49]
13.05.2022 09:19:10.714 *INFO* [OsgiInstallerImpl] org.apache.sling.audit.osgi.installer Started bundle org.apache.felix.metatype [50]
13.05.2022 09:19:10.714 *INFO* [OsgiInstallerImpl] org.apache.sling.audit.osgi.installer Started bundle org.apache.sling.commons.osgi [51]
13.05.2022 09:19:10.714 *INFO* [OsgiInstallerImpl] org.apache.sling.audit.osgi.installer Started bundle org.apache.sling.feature.extension.unpack [52]
13.05.2022 09:19:10.715 *INFO* [OsgiInstallerImpl] org.apache.sling.audit.osgi.installer Started bundle org.apache.sling.hc.api [53]
13.05.2022 09:19:10.715 *INFO* [OsgiInstallerImpl] org.apache.sling.audit.osgi.installer Started bundle org.apache.sling.installer.factory.feature [54]
13.05.2022 09:19:10.715 *INFO* [OsgiInstallerImpl] org.apache.sling.audit.osgi.installer Started bundle com.adobe.granite.localsdk [55]
13.05.2022 09:19:10.716 *INFO* [OsgiInstallerImpl] org.apache.sling.audit.osgi.installer Started bundle com.adobe.granite.toggle.api [56]
13.05.2022 09:19:10.716 *INFO* [OsgiInstallerImpl] org.apache.sling.audit.osgi.installer Started bundle org.apache.commons.commons-fileupload [57]
13.05.2022 09:19:10.716 *INFO* [OsgiInstallerImpl] org.apache.sling.audit.osgi.installer Started bundle org.apache.commons.lang3 [58]
13.05.2022 09:19:10.717 *INFO* [OsgiInstallerImpl] org.apache.sling.audit.osgi.installer Started bundle org.apache.commons.commons-text [59]
13.05.2022 09:19:10.717 *INFO* [OsgiInstallerImpl] org.apache.sling.audit.osgi.installer Started bundle org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient [60]
13.05.2022 09:19:10.717 *INFO* [OsgiInstallerImpl] org.apache.sling.audit.osgi.installer Started bundle org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore [61]
13.05.2022 09:19:10.718 *INFO* [OsgiInstallerImpl] org.apache.sling.audit.osgi.installer Started bundle joda-time [62]
13.05.2022 09:19:10.718 *INFO* [OsgiInstallerImpl] org.apache.sling.audit.osgi.installer Started bundle com.adobe.granite.bundles.json [63]
13.05.2022 09:19:10.718 *INFO* [OsgiInstallerImpl] org.apache.sling.audit.osgi.installer Started bundle io.dropwizard.metrics.core [64]
13.05.2022 09:19:10.718 *INFO* [OsgiInstallerImpl] org.apache.sling.audit.osgi.installer Started bundle org.apache.felix.healthcheck.core [65]
13.05.2022 09:19:10.719 *INFO* [OsgiInstallerImpl] org.apache.sling.audit.osgi.installer Started bundle org.apache.felix.healthcheck.generalchecks [66]
13.05.2022 09:19:10.719 *INFO* [OsgiInstallerImpl] org.apache.sling.audit.osgi.installer Started bundle org.apache.felix.healthcheck.webconsoleplugin [67]
13.05.2022 09:19:10.719 *INFO* [OsgiInstallerImpl] org.apache.sling.audit.osgi.installer Started bundle org.apache.felix.http.jetty [68]
13.05.2022 09:19:10.719 *INFO* [OsgiInstallerImpl] org.apache.sling.audit.osgi.installer Started bundle org.apache.felix.http.servlet-api [69]
13.05.2022 09:19:10.720 *INFO* [OsgiInstallerImpl] org.apache.sling.audit.osgi.installer Started bundle org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter [70]
13.05.2022 09:19:10.720 *INFO* [OsgiInstallerImpl] org.apache.sling.audit.osgi.installer Started bundle org.apache.felix.http.whiteboard [71]
13.05.2022 09:19:10.720 *INFO* [OsgiInstallerImpl] org.apache.sling.audit.osgi.installer Started bundle org.apache.felix.inventory [72]
13.05.2022 09:19:11.233 *INFO* [OsgiInstallerImpl] org.apache.sling.audit.osgi.installer Installed configuration org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.config~audit.log from resource TaskResource(url=launchpad:resources/config/org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.config-audit.log.config, entity=config:org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.config~audit.log, state=INSTALL, attributes=[org.apache.sling.installer.api.tasks.ResourceTransformer=:21:50:, service.factoryPid=org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.config, service.pid=audit.log], digest=a3ada85f0018f8dae4834b9cf6878803)
13.05.2022 09:19:11.235 *INFO* [OsgiInstallerImpl] org.apache.sling.audit.osgi.installer Installed configuration org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.config~auditlog.log from resource TaskResource(url=launchpad:resources/config/org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.config-auditlog.log.config, entity=config:org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.config~auditlog.log, state=INSTALL, attributes=[org.apache.sling.installer.api.tasks.ResourceTransformer=:21:50:, service.factoryPid=org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.config, service.pid=auditlog.log], digest=35753f20f663b89728bd15b1b8f0a925)
13.05.2022 09:19:11.237 *INFO* [OsgiInstallerImpl] org.apache.sling.audit.osgi.installer Installed configuration org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.config~history.config from resource TaskResource(url=launchpad:resources/config/org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.config-history.config.config, entity=config:org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.config~history.config, state=INSTALL, attributes=[org.apache.sling.installer.api.tasks.ResourceTransformer=:21:50:, service.factoryPid=org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.config, service.pid=history.config], digest=169a1f3c2e45eae02025509d08cc629a)
13.05.2022 09:19:11.238 *INFO* [OsgiInstallerImpl] org.apache.sling.audit.osgi.installer Installed configuration org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.config~queryrecorder.log from resource TaskResource(url=launchpad:resources/config/org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.config-queryrecorder.log.config, entity=config:org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.config~queryrecorder.log, state=INSTALL, attributes=[org.apache.sling.installer.api.tasks.ResourceTransformer=:21:50:, service.factoryPid=org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.config, service.pid=queryrecorder.log], digest=54ec47e919200b523465d13a2bc8a982)
13.05.2022 09:19:11.242 *INFO* [OsgiInstallerImpl] org.apache.sling.audit.osgi.installer Installed configuration org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.writer~access.log from resource TaskResource(url=launchpad:resources/config/org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.writer-access.log.config, entity=config:org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.writer~access.log, state=INSTALL, attributes=[org.apache.sling.installer.api.tasks.ResourceTransformer=:21:50:, service.factoryPid=org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.writer, service.pid=access.log], digest=580bd81a4d62beca378a0e5ed41d7b7d)
13.05.2022 09:19:11.243 *INFO* [OsgiInstallerImpl] org.apache.sling.audit.osgi.installer Installed configuration org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.writer~audit.log from resource TaskResource(url=launchpad:resources/config/org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.writer-audit.log.config, entity=config:org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.writer~audit.log, state=INSTALL, attributes=[org.apache.sling.installer.api.tasks.ResourceTransformer=:21:50:, service.factoryPid=org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.writer, service.pid=audit.log], digest=da2ebb57ffa4ed13e7023806b165f72e)
13.05.2022 09:19:11.246 *INFO* [OsgiInstallerImpl] org.apache.sling.audit.osgi.installer Installed configuration org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.writer~request.log from resource TaskResource(url=launchpad:resources/config/org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.writer-request.log.config, entity=config:org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.writer~request.log, state=INSTALL, attributes=[org.apache.sling.installer.api.tasks.ResourceTransformer=:21:50:, service.factoryPid=org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.writer, service.pid=request.log], digest=f7685e57bdbf60782630e948fcd65115)
13.05.2022 09:19:11.248 *INFO* [OsgiInstallerImpl] org.apache.sling.audit.osgi.installer Installed configuration org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.writer~upgrade.config from resource TaskResource(url=launchpad:resources/config/org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.writer-upgrade.config.config, entity=config:org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.writer~upgrade.config, state=INSTALL, attributes=[org.apache.sling.installer.api.tasks.ResourceTransformer=:21:50:, service.factoryPid=org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.writer, service.pid=upgrade.config], digest=c71ceefe46ecd22a944fc2d54310e218)
13.05.2022 09:19:11.253 *INFO* [OsgiInstallerImpl] org.apache.sling.audit.osgi.installer Installed configuration org.apache.sling.commons.metrics.rrd4j.impl.CodahaleMetricsReporter from resource TaskResource(url=launchpad:resources/config/org.apache.sling.commons.metrics.rrd4j.impl.CodahaleMetricsReporter.config, entity=config:org.apache.sling.commons.metrics.rrd4j.impl.CodahaleMetricsReporter, state=INSTALL, attributes=[org.apache.sling.installer.api.tasks.ResourceTransformer=:21:50:, service.pid=org.apache.sling.commons.metrics.rrd4j.impl.CodahaleMetricsReporter], digest=d55edd738928ed22b1cb9f40d67f96f)
13.05.2022 09:19:11.258 *INFO* [OsgiInstallerImpl] org.apache.sling.audit.osgi.installer Installed configuration org.apache.sling.commons.mime.internal.MimeTypeServiceImpl from resource TaskResource(url=launchpad:resources/config/org.apache.sling.commons.mime.internal.MimeTypeServiceImpl.config, entity=config:org.apache.sling.commons.mime.internal.MimeTypeServiceImpl, state=INSTALL, attributes=[org.apache.sling.installer.api.tasks.ResourceTransformer=:21:50:, service.pid=org.apache.sling.commons.mime.internal.MimeTypeServiceImpl], digest=8afcd55289d2858aa659f69ae1e065fc)
13.05.2022 09:19:11.261 *INFO* [OsgiInstallerImpl] org.apache.sling.audit.osgi.installer Installed configuration org.apache.sling.commons.scheduler.impl.QuartzScheduler from resource TaskResource(url=launchpad:resources/config/org.apache.sling.commons.scheduler.impl.QuartzScheduler.config, entity=config:org.apache.sling.commons.scheduler.impl.QuartzScheduler, state=INSTALL, attributes=[org.apache.sling.installer.api.tasks.ResourceTransformer=:21:50:, service.pid=org.apache.sling.commons.scheduler.impl.QuartzScheduler], digest=9ec865134ac64898d78e241f92fa3d25)
13.05.2022 09:19:11.264 *INFO* [OsgiInstallerImpl] org.apache.sling.audit.osgi.installer Installed configuration org.apache.sling.commons.threads.impl.DefaultThreadPool.factory~cq-asset-processing from resource TaskResource(url=launchpad:resources/config/org.apache.sling.commons.threads.impl.DefaultThreadPool.factory-cq-asset-processing.config, entity=config:org.apache.sling.commons.threads.impl.DefaultThreadPool.factory~cq-asset-processing, state=INSTALL, attributes=[org.apache.sling.installer.api.tasks.ResourceTransformer=:21:50:, service.factoryPid=org.apache.sling.commons.threads.impl.DefaultThreadPool.factory, service.pid=cq-asset-processing], digest=f16c63b052586e3bb720d4fbad6b51f3)
13.05.2022 09:19:11.266 *INFO* [OsgiInstallerImpl] org.apache.sling.audit.osgi.installer Installed configuration org.apache.sling.commons.threads.impl.DefaultThreadPool.factory~cq-polling-importer from resource TaskResource(url=launchpad:resources/config/org.apache.sling.commons.threads.impl.DefaultThreadPool.factory-cq-polling-importer.config, entity=config:org.apache.sling.commons.threads.impl.DefaultThreadPool.factory~cq-polling-importer, state=INSTALL, attributes=[org.apache.sling.installer.api.tasks.ResourceTransformer=:21:50:, service.factoryPid=org.apache.sling.commons.threads.impl.DefaultThreadPool.factory, service.pid=cq-polling-importer], digest=bcc53ef50ac7a75afebd015afe94d402)
ESAPI: WARNING: System property [org.owasp.esapi.opsteam] is not set
ESAPI: WARNING: System property [org.owasp.esapi.devteam] is not set
ESAPI: Attempting to load ESAPI.properties via file I/O.
ESAPI: Attempting to load ESAPI.properties as resource file via file I/O.
ESAPI: Not found in 'org.owasp.esapi.resources' directory or file not readable: /Users/<user>/aem-sdk/publish/ESAPI.properties
ESAPI: Not found in SystemResource Directory/resourceDirectory: .esapi/ESAPI.properties
ESAPI: Not found in 'user.home' (/Users/<user>) directory: /Users/<user>/esapi/ESAPI.properties
ESAPI: Loading ESAPI.properties via file I/O failed. Exception was: java.io.FileNotFoundException
ESAPI: Attempting to load ESAPI.properties via the classpath.
ESAPI: SUCCESSFULLY LOADED ESAPI.properties via the CLASSPATH from '/ (root)' using class loader for DefaultSecurityConfiguration class!
ESAPI: SecurityConfiguration for Validator.ConfigurationFile.MultiValued not found in ESAPI.properties. Using default: false
ESAPI: Attempting to load validation.properties via file I/O.
ESAPI: Attempting to load validation.properties as resource file via file I/O.
ESAPI: Not found in 'org.owasp.esapi.resources' directory or file not readable: /Users/<user>/aem-sdk/publish/validation.properties
ESAPI: Not found in SystemResource Directory/resourceDirectory: .esapi/validation.properties
ESAPI: Not found in 'user.home' (/Users/<user>) directory: /Users/<user>/esapi/validation.properties
ESAPI: Loading validation.properties via file I/O failed.
ESAPI: Attempting to load validation.properties via the classpath.
ESAPI: SUCCESSFULLY LOADED validation.properties via the CLASSPATH from '/ (root)' using class loader for DefaultSecurityConfiguration class!
```

`stderr.log`

```
Low-memory action set to fork
Using 64bit VM settings, min.heap=1024MB, min permgen=256MB, default fork arguments=[-Xmx1024m, -XX:MaxPermSize=256m]
The JVM reports a heap size of 4096 MB, meets our expectation of 1024 MB +/- 20
Setting properties from filename '/Users/<user>/aem-sdk/publish/aem-publish-p4503.jar'
Option '-quickstart.server.port' set to '4503' from filename aem-publish-p4503.jar
Option '-r' set to 'publish' from filename aem-publish-p4503.jar
Setting 'sling.run.modes' to 'publish' from filename.
Verbose option not active, closing stdin and redirecting stdout and stderr
Redirecting stdout to /Users/<user>/aem-sdk/publish/crx-quickstart/logs/stdout.log
Redirecting stderr to /Users/<user>/aem-sdk/publish/crx-quickstart/logs/stderr.log
ResourceProvider paths=[/gui, /gui/default]
May 13, 2022 9:19:11 AM org.apache.sling.feature.apiregions.impl.ResolverHookImpl pruneCoveredCaps
INFO: Removing candidate [org.apache.aries.transaction.manager [43](R 43.0)] osgi.wiring.package; {bundle-symbolic-name=org.apache.aries.transaction.manager, bundle-version=1.2.0, version=1.1.0, osgi.wiring.package=javax.transaction.xa} which is in region null as more specific candidate(s) are available in regions [org.apache.felix.framework [0](R 0)] osgi.wiring.package; {bundle-symbolic-name=[Ljava.lang.String;@1d1febc0, bundle-version=7.0.3, version=1.1.0, osgi.wiring.package=javax.transaction.xa} region null
May 13, 2022 9:19:11 AM org.apache.sling.feature.apiregions.impl.ResolverHookImpl filterMatches
INFO: API-Regions removed candidates [org.apache.aries.transaction.manager [43](R 43.0)] osgi.wiring.package; {bundle-symbolic-name=org.apache.aries.transaction.manager, bundle-version=1.2.0, version=1.1.0, osgi.wiring.package=javax.transaction.xa}[Regions: [], Feature: null] for requirement [org.apache.aries.transaction.manager [43](R 43.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.transaction.xa)(version>=1.1.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) as the requirement is in the following regions: [com.adobe.aem.deprecated, global, com.adobe.aem.internal] and in feature: [com.day.cq:cq-quickstart:slingosgifeature:base:2022.4.7138.20220427T075748Z-220401]
May 13, 2022 9:19:25 AM org.apache.sling.feature.apiregions.impl.ResolverHookImpl filterMatches
WARNING: API-Regions removed candidates [com.adobe.granite.poi [101](R 101.0)] osgi.wiring.package; {bundle-symbolic-name=com.adobe.granite.poi, bundle-version=2.0.42, version=2.11.0, osgi.wiring.package=com.drew.imaging.riff}[Regions: [], Feature: com.day.cq:cq-quickstart:slingosgifeature:base:2022.4.7138.20220427T075748Z-220401] for requirement [org.apache.tika.parsers [115](R 115.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=com.drew.imaging.riff) as the requirement is in the following regions: [com.adobe.aem.deprecated, global, com.adobe.aem.internal] and in feature: [com.day.cq:cq-quickstart:slingosgifeature:base-granite:2022.4.7138.20220427T075748Z-220401]
May 13, 2022 9:19:25 AM org.apache.sling.feature.apiregions.impl.ResolverHookImpl filterMatches
WARNING: API-Regions removed candidates [com.adobe.granite.poi [101](R 101.0)] osgi.wiring.package; {bundle-symbolic-name=com.adobe.granite.poi, bundle-version=2.0.42, version=2.11.0, osgi.wiring.package=com.drew.imaging.webp}[Regions: [], Feature: com.day.cq:cq-quickstart:slingosgifeature:base:2022.4.7138.20220427T075748Z-220401] for requirement [org.apache.tika.parsers [115](R 115.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=com.drew.imaging.webp) as the requirement is in the following regions: [com.adobe.aem.deprecated, global, com.adobe.aem.internal] and in feature: [com.day.cq:cq-quickstart:slingosgifeature:base-granite:2022.4.7138.20220427T075748Z-220401]
May 13, 2022 9:19:25 AM org.apache.sling.feature.apiregions.impl.ResolverHookImpl filterMatches
WARNING: API-Regions removed candidates [com.adobe.granite.poi [101](R 101.0)] osgi.wiring.package; {bundle-symbolic-name=com.adobe.granite.poi, bundle-version=2.0.42, version=3.0.0, osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.poi.ooxml.extractor}[Regions: [], Feature: com.day.cq:cq-quickstart:slingosgifeature:base:2022.4.7138.20220427T075748Z-220401] for requirement [org.apache.tika.parsers [115](R 115.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.poi.ooxml.extractor) as the requirement is in the following regions: [com.adobe.aem.deprecated, global, com.adobe.aem.internal] and in feature: [com.day.cq:cq-quickstart:slingosgifeature:base-granite:2022.4.7138.20220427T075748Z-220401]
May 13, 2022 9:19:25 AM org.apache.sling.feature.apiregions.impl.ResolverHookImpl filterMatches
WARNING: API-Regions removed candidates [com.adobe.granite.poi [101](R 101.0)] osgi.wiring.package; {bundle-symbolic-name=com.adobe.granite.poi, bundle-version=2.0.42, version=3.0.0, osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.poi.ooxml.util}[Regions: [], Feature: com.day.cq:cq-quickstart:slingosgifeature:base:2022.4.7138.20220427T075748Z-220401] for requirement [org.apache.tika.parsers [115](R 115.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.poi.ooxml.util) as the requirement is in the following regions: [com.adobe.aem.deprecated, global, com.adobe.aem.internal] and in feature: [com.day.cq:cq-quickstart:slingosgifeature:base-granite:2022.4.7138.20220427T075748Z-220401]
May 13, 2022 9:19:25 AM org.apache.tika.config.InitializableProblemHandler$3 handleInitializableProblem
WARNING: org.xerial's sqlite-jdbc is not loaded.
Please provide the jar on your classpath to parse sqlite files.
See tika-parsers/pom.xml for the correct version.
May 13, 2022 9:20:44 AM org.apache.sling.feature.apiregions.impl.ResolverHookImpl filterMatches
WARNING: API-Regions removed candidates [com.adobe.granite.poi [101](R 101.0)] osgi.wiring.package; {bundle-symbolic-name=com.adobe.granite.poi, bundle-version=2.0.42, version=2.0.6, osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.xpath.saxon}[Regions: [], Feature: com.day.cq:cq-quickstart:slingosgifeature:base:2022.4.7138.20220427T075748Z-220401] for requirement [com.day.cq.dam.cq-dam-word [372](R 372.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.xpath.saxon) as the requirement is in the following regions: [com.adobe.aem.deprecated, global, com.adobe.aem.internal] and in feature: [com.day.cq:cq-quickstart:slingosgifeature:cq-assets-model_quickstart:2022.4.7138.20220427T075748Z-220401]
May 13, 2022 9:20:44 AM org.apache.sling.feature.apiregions.impl.ResolverHookImpl filterMatches
WARNING: API-Regions removed candidates [com.adobe.granite.poi [101](R 101.0)] osgi.wiring.package; {bundle-symbolic-name=com.adobe.granite.poi, bundle-version=2.0.42, version=2.0.6, osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.xquery.saxon}[Regions: [], Feature: com.day.cq:cq-quickstart:slingosgifeature:base:2022.4.7138.20220427T075748Z-220401] for requirement [com.day.cq.dam.cq-dam-word [372](R 372.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.xquery.saxon) as the requirement is in the following regions: [com.adobe.aem.deprecated, global, com.adobe.aem.internal] and in feature: [com.day.cq:cq-quickstart:slingosgifeature:cq-assets-model_quickstart:2022.4.7138.20220427T075748Z-220401]
May 13, 2022 9:20:49 AM it.tidalwave.imageio.util.Logger info
INFO: Installing RAWProcessor...
May 13, 2022 9:20:49 AM it.tidalwave.imageio.util.Logger info
INFO: Installed RAWProcessor
RAWProcessor succesfully installed
Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
Opening browser using cmd=open http://localhost:4503/
Installation time:167 seconds
http://localhost:4503/
Quickstart started
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because i am a dumb-dumb. The publisher publishes content and makes it available to the web (or the localhost in my case). For any of the non-admin pages to work some content needs to be published first.

To verify that the publisher server is running http://localhost:4503/crx/packmgr/index.jsp if you see CRX, everything is working as expected and you need to write some content in the author and let it replicate to the publisher (if you have that enabled) or directly deploy to the publisher instance.